# Feature to Raster Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, convert, fields-attributes, rasterization

I am attempting to rasterize a point layer using the Feature to Raster conversion tool. Each attempt, I receive the following error codes:

- ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: CellLyrCreateInternal: Grid: n:... alrady exists
- ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression

This layer does not already exist. Can attribute field type (double vs float vs integer) produce this problem? Each time I try to change field types, or create a new attribute column of a different field type in either ArcMap or ArcCatalog, the column will revert to double, no matter which type I set it as. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try rebooting pc?

Comment: Perhaps it's referring to an intermediate "temporary" grid created in memory for processing, rather than the output? Rebooting is a good idea, but you can also change the scratch workspace (or try logging in as a different user). Data type should not matter, as the output raster will simply match the input type. You cannot change an attribute data type once it's been created. It is a bit odd you can't create a new attribute of a different data type and that it reverts to double.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. Reducing the precision of the attribute field turned out to be the fix. In addition, I discovered that if I selected an attribute field precision of greater than 7 for a float field type, the field type would revert to double.

Comment: That's because floats can't have a precision greater than six. See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000001m000000